# Google Cast v3 (Android), issue while stop casting when timeout

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I recently started working with `Google Cast SDK v3(Android App)`.

I am working on casting audio streams on cast device, it works well untill any stream throw failure callback (FAILURE STATUS CODE : 15 (TIMEOUT)) in setResultCallback and cast device stuck on loading screen, i tried using

```
remoteMediaClient.stop()
```

method, but it doesn't work and also it stops playing other streams as well after failure.

I am looking forward for a way to clear Media request which i made earlier to cast device, so that i will be able to load new stream on cast device.

Here is the stream that stuck on Buffering state while playing:
http://14523.live.streamtheworld.com/KALLAMAAC

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what your setup is; when you call stop(), it not only stops the playback, it clears/unloads the media and any queue that you have so to play another item afterward, you need to load the media again, as if nothing was playing back before; it is rare to call stop(). To be able to help you further, it is important to see what type of error your receiver is running into.